# Is it possible to have a cover for an unbounded set that is not the set of Real Numbers?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am trying to get the intuition of compact sets and why they have to be bounded.

Comment: Heine-Borel Theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Borel_theorem

Comment: @Oria Gruber Thanks.

Comment: If $C\subseteq\mathbb R$ then the sets $C\cap(-n,n)$ for $n=1,2,\dots$ cover the set $C$ and are open sets in subspace $C$. If $C$ is compact then there is a finite subcover so that $C\subseteq(-n,n)$ for some $n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the fact that the set is unbounded , if you take a covering by bounded open sets (can you prove it always exists?) It will not be possible to extract a finite subset that is itself a covering.

If it were possible, you would have proven that the original set is bounded because it would be contained in the closure of an union of a finite number of open sets.

Comment: Ok.  I understand how you could use an infinite number of bounded open sets to cover, if it is unbounded, but not a finite amount of open sets.   How can you always prove that a cover that exists for an infinite or unbounded set?  It is because a set can be the cover of itself right?  Please correct me if I am wrong on this.

Comment: Unbounded sets are not compact so this finite cover does not exist (usually).

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question in the title is yes. For instance, *any* subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (potentially unbounded) is covered by the collection of open intervals $(-n, n)$ (over all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, since
$$
\mathbb{R} = (-1, 1) \cup (-2, 2) \cup (-3, 3) \cup \ldots.
$$
However, the reason why an unbounded set cannot be compact is that if we take this cover in particular, it has no finite subcover. Do you see why there is no finite subcover of the above for an unbounded set?

Comment: Because if you can't remove any of those sets or else it wouldn't be covered right?